# I need to get my p-tag to get on a new line, any one who knows?

Tags: html

So, I am making this site where I have a problem. As you can see, it's a little weird. I want the number 2 to be on the next line, but I don't know how.

It seems like, when I put in the `<br>` tag, everything is going down, but when I don't have the `<br>` tag, it works. Please help.

```css
body{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Verdana', sherif;
}

.nav{
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: #000000;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 0 20px 0;
  border-top: solid 2px #f0f0f0;
  border-bottom: solid 2px #f0f0f0;
  margin: 0px;
}

.nav > li{
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 25px 0 25px;
}

.nav >li >a{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

.nav >li > a:hover{
  color: grey;
}

.button {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  border: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
  border-radius: 1px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.button:hover {
  background-color: orange;
  color: black;
}

.text {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Appetitten Pizza & Grill | Pizza</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css2.css">
  </head>

  <body>

    <center>

      <div style="width:70%">

        <div style="float:center; margin-bottom:0px">
          <a href="forside.html"><img src="something-logo.png"></a>
        </div>

        <div style="margin-top:0px">
          <ul class="nav" style="margin-bottom:0px">
            <li><a href="pizza.html"><font size="5">Some thing</font></a></li>
            <li><a href="hamburger.html"><font size="5">Some thing</font></a></li>
            <li><a href="kebab.html"><font size="5">Some thing</font></a></li>
            <li><a href="salater.html"><font size="5">Some thing</font></a></li>
            <li><a href="om-oss.html"><font size="5">Some thing</font></a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>

        <div style="width:70%;float:center">

          <div style="width:100%; float:center">
            <div style="float:center; width:100%">
              <div style="float:left; width:10%">
                <p><strong>Nr:</strong></p>
              </div>
              <div style="float:left; width:75%">
                <p align="left"><strong>Some thing:</strong></p>
              </div>
              <div style="float:left; width:15%">
                <p><strong>Price:</strong></p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div style="width:100%; float:center">
            <div style="float:center; width:100%">
              <div style="float:left; width:10%">
                <p>1.</p>
              </div>
              <div style="float:left; width:75%">
                <p align="left"><strong>Thing:</strong><br>(here is going to be some ingrediants)</p>
              </div>
              <div style="float:left; width:15%">
                <p>10 $</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          
          <div style="width:100%; float:center">
            <div style="float:center; width:100%">
              <div style="float:left; width:10%">
                <p>2.</p>
              </div>
              <div style="float:left; width:75%">
                <p align="left"><strong>Thing:</strong><br>(here is going to be some ingrediants)</p>
              </div>
              <div style="float:left; width:15%">
                <p>10 $</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
         </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

add this div tag just above your `<p>` tag

```
<div class="NL"></div>
```

and this css line in your css file

```
.NL
{
clear:both;
}
```